# How can I react on reject votes on my suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I edited a question by including code that the OP put in a comment. First I asked him to put the code in the question and format it as code. Some time later, I looked at the question again, and edited his code into his question. So far, the edit was accepted by two people and rejected by another for this reason:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service,
>   or is deliberately destructive

I am guessing that there is a list of reasons to not approve an edit, and this must be one of them, but there is no way for me to either remove the edit (I didn't mean any harm, and am not promoting anything) or provide information to the person who rejected it for clarification.

What is the best thing to do?

Comment: Reviewers spend 6 to 8 seconds on a review and routinely reject a code change.  A "formatted code" comment on the edit doesn't cut it.  You did not format the code, you modified it.  But three other reviewers caught the real reason, that's blind luck you cannot count on.  You'll at a minimum have to provide a better comment, something like "include OP's comment into the question".

Answer (score 11):

I just approved your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12961386).

In general, it is frowned upon if code is edited, especially in questions, as it might alter the question and, therefore, the problem. If you still insist, leave a clear comment in the Edit Summary.

> Comment: formatted code

That doesn't tell a reviewer anything, they see that. What is worse in your specific case is that the code you added doesn't come from a comment on the question but from a comment on your answer.

To be a bit more on the safe side, you should have said:

> Moved the HTML mark-up left as a comment by the OP on my answer into the question

That wouldn't guarantee that editors accept your edit, but you make the chance higher that it gets accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I will be more judicious and comment more clearly

Answer (score 8):

The edit summary can help mitigate this issue in the future.  Simply point them to the exact comment that the code was placed into and state that you're adding what the OP themselves had posted.

The hope here is that at least one more person will come along and see that yes, the comments in that question *did* contain the code, and will agree with the edit.  If they don't, then don't get too discouraged, but be sure to include the context in the future.